# News feed SP Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, filter, modern-experience, newsfeed, sharepoint-news

Is it possible to grabs news from different site?

If I select news source: this site, everything is working fine and I have all the needed filters but as soon as I change to different news source: main site, all filter options are gone.

Is there a way to show news from main site to different multiple site?

Filter on:
I am able filter news feed here on current site

[image: x]

Filter gone:
Can't filter news feed that comes from a different site

[image: x]

Comment: Can you please add any screenshot? Where are you getting the filters? Where you want the filters?

Comment: Images were added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a default behavior of News wepart in SharePoint Online.

Filtering is **not supported when you are using News source from other site**.

If you want Microsoft to include this feature then I will suggest you to submit a [User Voice](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/) to Microsoft. It is a place for customers to provide feedback about Microsoft SharePoint products.

**Other References**: [Use the News web part on a SharePoint page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-the-news-web-part-on-a-sharepoint-page-c2dcee50-f5d7-434b-8cb9-a7feefd9f165).

Comment: Thank you a lot. I will check them out